# Auto-Smooth is greyed out and can't be enabled

Tags: shaders, smooth

Why does auto-smooth seem to be disabled on my model even when i turn it on?

And when I turn it on, the following problems occur:
[image]
face orientation is correct:
[image]
Unfortunately, i cannot work without auto-smoothing, because the model must be attached to another rounded model. How to make these polygons look like the rest of the model?

UPD:
I found out that the problem is in normals, but auto-smoothing still disabled and not working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a split normals problem (the split normals are the normals that determine the shading), it typically happens with imported fbx, go into the *Object Data panel > Geometry* and click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]